# How to design an architecture of a system as described by Uncle Bob?

Tags: design, architecture, object-oriented-design

As per the "Software Architecture" explained by Uncle Bob, your architecture should be able to defer the framework and DB related decisions as much as possible.

Consider an example of a Payroll system to be developed in Java. I assume that the core application will be a standalone jar file. The "delivery mechanism" will be over the web, a separate war file. The DB will again be a separate jar file.

The webapp as well as the DB project should be dependent on the core application.

I am a bit confused here, how to organize different projects? The webapp will have the core application as a dependency. So, what about the DB project?

Comment: The organization of your project is entirely up to you.  Your project's organization doesn't really have much to do with your software architecture, except that good organization tends to reflect the architectural perspective.  Make sure you understand *why* Bob's principles apply in specific situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your core application should go into a (static) library - or possible multiple libraries, one for the entities, one or more others for use cases, etc. This depends on the size of your application. For simplicity, I'll assume that the entities and use cases are all in a core library.

The core library contains interfaces for communicating with the rest of the world.

Now you can have additional infrastructure libraries:

- a library for the web-interface
- a library for the DB

Both of these implement some of the core library's interfaces, so they obviously have a dependency on the core library (but not the other way around). Therefore, you can replace any of them later with a different implementation.

The core library classes expect to be given implementations of the interfaces. This is where you "plug in" the actual implementations from your infrastructure libraries. For this purpose, you will have a separate project that ties all of your libraries together via dependency injection, and produces your final executable that you can deploy.

Typically, your DB and webapp will not be *literally* plugins in the sense that they are dynamically loaded at runtime. Rather, they are kept separately only until the final executable is created.

Of course, you can have the DB, etc. as dynamically loaded libraries, but this only makes sense if you have some reason for extending the functionality after deployment.

Final notes: nothing forces you to put things into separate libraries, but I recommend it. Also, I'm still waiting for the clean architecture book, but I'm assuming it will basically follow [this one](https://8thlight.com/blog/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html).

---

**Extending my answer to address your comment**

Maybe I can clarify with a more specific example:

If you use an IDE, and you create a java project, it will probably ask you whether you want to create a library, or an executable. First, you create a library, called "core".

In that library, you implement your controllers (e.g. `ReportController`, `EmployeeManager`), your entities (e.g. `Report`, `Employee`, `Department`, etc.) and **interfaces** for things like database access - e.g. `EmployeeRepository`. The `EmployeeManager` takes a reference to an `EmployeeRepository` in its constructor that it can use to add and remove employees. (See dependency injection).

Now you might create a new library project and call it "mysqlDB". You make it reference your core library and create a class `MysqlEmployeeRepository` that implements `EmployeeRepository`. Separating this out allows you to later replace it with an `OracleEmployeeRepository` without having to touch the core library at all. This is what's meant by the DB being a plug in to the application.

However, usually (for moderately sized projects), there is no need to allow for the DB to be plugged in at runtime. Instead, you often just want to end up with a single executable that you can deploy. So as a final step, you add a new project called "MyPayrollSystem" that references your core library, your DB library and the rest.

In this project, all you do is

- create an instance of your `MysqlEmployeeRepository`
- create an instance of your `EmployeeManager` and give it your `MysqlEmployeeRepository` instance.
- do similar things to set up all other parts of your system, e.g. the web interface

What you end up with is a complete self-contained executable, but your individual components are only put together (plugged in) in the last part of your compilation.

Again, I want to stress that this is not the only way to do it. Sometimes, you may want to defer loading the correct library even more (i.e. to runtime), so you may load the DB library dynamically depending on a config file or command line parameters. But this is a step you should only take if your really need it.

Comment: I got the overall idea now. I am still a bit unsure how to achieve the "you will have a separate project that ties all of your libraries together via dependency injection" thing in a real life project, but still, I get the high-level picture.

Comment: I have edited my answer. I hope this clears up how the parts are eventually assembled and why.

Answer (score 1):

As Uncle Bob says, your application should be the group of use cases that define it, as well as the business rules that you have.

Regardless of your project's organization, you should be able to test your business rules (application) without any Web app or DB. The data persistence must be a plugin to your application.

Any additional component must be a plugin to your application, and in production you can resolve all dependencies in the initialization (eg: use Dependency Injection to make your application rely on abstractions, and in the 'main' part of your actual application, you resolve all dependencies using some DI framework).

If you can achieve the above, the your project's organization will reflect its architecture naturally.

Comment: Exactly, the GUI (Webapp) and the DB should be a plugin. This means that the webapp depends upon the application, the DB depends upon the application. How do you achieve such a structure with Java/Maven? I am sure you can add the dependencies as a jar file, but how will you deploy it?